# vlookup for cell colors using vba

Tags: vba, colors, lookup

I have looked around this site (and others) for an answer, but I have not been able to look for a correct solution, after three years. I don't want to use conditional formatting because I am adding cells and changing the colors constantly. So I am looking for a vba solution but I am not an expert here.

I have one worksheet with 20 different values (cells a1 to t1). In that same worksheet I have used vba to extract the RGB values of each cell (a2 to t4). In a different worksheet a have a 5000+ table and in two of the columns I select one of the 20 values (from the other wsheet) from a drop-down list. What I need is the color to automatically update to match the color in the first wsheet.

I have this code, which I see as very primitive, that is actually working but for every change I make it takes long to update the whole workbook and it is annoying and unefficient. I need support in making this work better.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6, Name7, Name8, Name9, Name10,
Name11, Name12, Name13, Name14, Name15, Name16, Name17, Name18, Name19,  
Name20 As String
Name1 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name1")
Name2 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name2")
Name3 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name3")
Name4 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name4")
Name5 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name5")
Name6 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name6")
Name7 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name7")
Name8 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name8")
Name9 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name9")
Name10 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name10")
Name11 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name11")
Name12 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name12")
Name13 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name13")
Name14 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name14")
Name15 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name15")
Name16 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name16")
Name17 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name17")
Name18 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name18")
Name19 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name19")
Name20 = Worksheets("C").Range("Name20")

Dim Red1, Green1, Blue1, Red2, Green2, Blue2, Red3, Green3, Blue3, Red4, 
Green4, Blue4, Red5, Green5, Blue5, Red6, Green6, Blue6, Red7, Green7, 
Blue7, Red8, Green8, Blue8, Red9, Green9, Blue9, Red10, Green10, Blue10, 
Red11, Green11, Blue11, Red12, Green12, Blue12, Red13, Green13, Blue13, 
Red14, Green14, Blue14, Red15, Green15, Blue15, Red16, Green16, Blue16, 
Red17, Green17, Blue17, Red18, Green18, Blue18, Red19, Green19, Blue19, 
Red20, Green20, Blue20 As Integer
Red1 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo1")
Green1 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde1")
Blue1 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul1")
Red2 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo2")
Green2 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde2")
Blue2 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul2")
Red3 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo3")
Green3 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde3")
Blue3 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul3")
Red4 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo4")
Green4 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde4")
Blue4 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul4")
Red5 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo5")
Green5 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde5")
Blue5 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul5")
Red6 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo6")
Green6 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde6")
Blue6 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul6")
Red7 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo7")
Green7 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde7")
Blue7 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul7")
Red8 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo8")
Green8 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde8")
Blue8 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul8")
Red9 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo9")
Green9 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde9")
Blue9 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul9")
Red10 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo10")
Green10 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde10")
Blue10 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul10")
Red11 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo11")
Green11 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde11")
Blue11 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul11")
Red12 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo12")
Green12 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde12")
Blue12 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul12")
Red13 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo13")
Green13 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde13")
Blue13 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul13")
Red14 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo14")
Green14 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde14")
Blue14 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul14")
Red15 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo15")
Green15 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde15")
Blue15 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul15")
Red16 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo16")
Green16 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde16")
Blue16 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul16")
Red17 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo17")
Green17 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde17")
Blue17 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul17")
Red18 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo18")
Green18 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde18")
Blue18 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul18")
Red19 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo19")
Green19 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde19")
Blue19 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul19")
Red20 = Worksheets("C").Range("Rojo20")
Green20 = Worksheets("C").Range("Verde20")
Blue20 = Worksheets("C").Range("Azul20")

For Each cell In Range("b4:o23") 'change cell range as needed

Select Case cell.Value
Case Name1
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red1, Green1, Blue1)
Case Name2
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red2, Green2, Blue2)
Case Name3
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red3, Green3, Blue3)
Case Name4
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red4, Green4, Blue4)
Case Name5
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red5, Green5, Blue5)
Case Name6
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red6, Green6, Blue6)
Case Name7
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red7, Green7, Blue7)
Case Name8
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red8, Green8, Blue8)
Case Name9
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red9, Green9, Blue9)
Case Name10
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red10, Green10, Blue10)
Case Name11
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red11, Green11, Blue11)
Case Name12
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red12, Green12, Blue12)
Case Name13
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red13, Green13, Blue13)
Case Name14
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red14, Green14, Blue14)
Case Name15
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red15, Green15, Blue15)
Case Name16
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red16, Green16, Blue16)
Case Name17
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red17, Green17, Blue17)
Case Name18
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red18, Green18, Blue18)
Case Name19
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red19, Green19, Blue19)
Case Name20
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red20, Green20, Blue20)
Case Else
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Select

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, your first variable block is not working how you think it is. You have declared `Name20` as `String`. The rest of your variables are being pushed into `Variant`

Comment: If all of those named ranges are arranged in a tabular form then your code could use a vlookup and be many times shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngLookup As Range, rng As Range, m, c As Range

    Set rngLookup = Sheets("C").Range("A1:T1")
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B4:O23"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            m = Application.Match(c.Value, rngLookup, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                c.Interior.Color = rngLookup.Cells(m).Interior.Color
            Else
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

Note - simplified this further just extracting the "key" cell color directly (no need to extract and store the separate R, G and B values)

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for such a simple answer. Thank you very much