# Fill text from left table by matching color in right table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, row

I want to fill the text from table on the left to table on the right matched by cell color to column color. Add (concatenate) texts if two cell in a row in left table are same. What should I do?

[image: Table for reference]

Comment: ...Add (concatenate) texts if two cell in a row in left table are same... color? Or ... text? Couldn't occur 3 cells the same (color or text)?

Comment: I would redesign your tables so that you're not using colour as data.

Comment: I think this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498970/12634230